# Keep folder and tables in sync while backing upp live Laravel app

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, digital-ocean, laravel-forge

I need to back up back up my live Laravel app daily, and also the content of a specific folder where the user's uploaded pictures are stored.

I've searched around and understood that it's possible to do this with various Laravel packages, but **is there any way to make sure that the database/folder is not altered by users during the backup process?**

I want to avoid scenarios like these:

- Table D is altered but first
  after table A is backed up, messing up the relation between them. So
  when the DB backup is complete there could be a different amount of
  rows in table A and table D, even though they need to have the same
  amount of rows.
- A user has 10 picture in his folder and during the backup process he
  deletes one picture. The deletion is made after the table keeping track of user images is backed up, but before the users' picture folder is backed up. So
  when the backup is done the database will state that the user has 10
  images, but there will only be 9 images backed up.

I find it a bit hard to explain but I hope you understand.

**Maybe setting up a cronjob would do?**

**Would it then be possible to set the app in maintenance mode, and only remove that mode once the backup is 100% complete?**

If possible I would prefer to do the backing up without having to set up a maintenance mode though.

I'm using mysql and Laravel 5.3 on Digital Ocean, and have Laravel forge, if it's of any relevance.

I would be very grateful for any suggestions, thanks! :)

Comment: You are looking for this package: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-backup

Comment: `php artisan down` puts the app in maintenance mode and `php artisan up` reverses it.

Comment: yes, I was thinking of using php artisan up and dow, and the backup in between. is it possible to run the up command first after the backup is complete?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Digital Ocean the answer is simple: a Live Snapshot of your server. Works like a charm, 0 downtime, and very easy to revert to should something happen :-)

Mind you this only works if you have the DB hosted on your webserver!

Comment: thanks for the reply, but from what I've read both snapshots and backups requires powering down the droplet in order to keep the data in sync

Comment: It is always advised, but not required anymore :) Before you had to shut down your server, but that changed recently: https://mobile.twitter.com/digitalocean/status/751140236298706947?lang=en